# How to fix FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to rename multiple files from a folder so that every alphabet is removed but i get this error when I run it:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified: 'Amsterdam1971' -> '1971'

```
import os
os.chdir(directory)
for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    os.rename(f_name,f_name.translate(str.maketrans("","","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue since you are trying to update the file name without the extension. You should add the file extension to fix this issue.

```
import os
os.chdir(directory)
for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    os.rename(f_name+'.'+f_ext,f_name.translate(str.maketrans("","","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))+'.'+f_ext)
```